# I can't I use my code certificate to sign my .exe file (EKU filter)

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, ssl-certificate

I created a code certificate using:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -dnsname testcert.test.io
$cert 

$secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password1234' -Force -AsPlainText

$certPath = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$($cert.Thumbprint)"
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certPath -FilePath C:\selfcert.pfx -Password $secPassword
```

I'm trying to use it to sign my .exe using:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /debug /f "C:\selfcert.pfx" /p password1234 "A:\mysoft\sign\myexe.EXE"
```

the debug throws this:

```
The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: testcert.test.io
    Issued by: testcert.test.io
    Expires:   Fri Aug 12 15:25:13 2022
    SHA1 hash: 0CDA91D628CA855B49FA1CB8DFD0F53C121BEB27

After EKU filter, 0 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 0 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Running certmgr shows my certificate in Personal>certificates as testcert.test.io (I suppose because of the dnsname)

What I think, (it is my first time trying to certificate a .exe so I might be wrong) it means that my certificate is not passing the EKU filter, afaik EKU filter means certificates that are listed as trusted (I'm not sure on that one)

What am I doing wrong? or what am I missing to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a`Code Signing`-Certificate, which means that it has an Extended Key Usage (EKU) with the Code signing Object Identifier (OID).

```
$ku_codeSigning = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3";

  $codeSignCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
    -Type "CodeSigningCert" `
    -KeyExportPolicy "Exportable" `
    -Subject "..." `
    -KeyUsageProperty @("Sign") `
    -KeyUsage @("DigitalSignature") `
    -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}$($ku_codeSigning)", "2.5.29.19={text}false") `
    -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\My `
    -KeyLength 2048 `
    -NotAfter ([DateTime]::Now.AddDays(90)) `
    -Provider "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" `
    -Signer $subCaCert;
```

The `-Signer` argument is used to create a trust chain consisting of a root and a sub CA certificate.

```
  $rootCaCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
    -Type "Custom" `
    -KeyExportPolicy "Exportable" `
    -KeyUsageProperty "All" `
    -KeyUsage @("CertSign", "CrlSign") `
    -Subject "My Fake Root CA" `
    -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My `
    -NotAfter ([DateTime]::Now.AddYears(20)) `
    -Provider "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" `
    -KeyLength 4096 `
    -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19={text}cA=true&pathLength=1");

 $subCaCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
    -Type "Custom" `
    -KeyExportPolicy "Exportable" `
    -KeyUsageProperty "All" `
    -KeyUsage @("CertSign", "CrlSign") `
    -Subject "My Fake Sub CA" `
    -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My `
    -NotAfter ([DateTime]::Now.AddYears(5)) `
    -Provider "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" `
    -KeyLength 4096 `
    -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19={text}cA=true&pathLength=0") `
    -Signer $rootCaCert;
```

Comment: I'm trying to run it in Powershell but I get this error: Cannot bind parameter 'Signer' to the target. what could be a valid value for the variable $subCaCert ?

Comment: The `-Signer` argument allows you to build a trust chain (create a CA certificate to put into your trust store and have all signed/issued certificates trusted). If you just want to have 1 certificate your can just omit it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Comment: Thank  you I was able to create a .pfx that passes the EKU filter with your solution I just added a password and "Export-PfxCertificate", also I changed the "-CertStoreLocation" to "cert:\CurrentUser\My" many thanks

Comment: I was not required to create the Signer cert, it worked without it. :-)

Comment: Every certificate with digital signature capabilities is eligible to sign. It is the processes and lifecycle that will make it easier, if you distinguish certificates by their purpose (trust chain and signer in this case).